# filling in a data.table with information from multiple objects in R

Tags: r, loops, data.table

Within a large function, I would like to create a "summary table" of sorts. This summary table, summaries information from multiple R objects, that have been created within the function. The objects are:

Data table with the information on the limit

```
>     str(limit)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id   : num 6292
 $ type : chr "DAILY"
 $ value: chr "350"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

vector with position of the element in `mydata` that is over the limit `limits$value`

```
n <- which(mydata$amount > as.double(limit$value))
str(n)
int [1:4960] 1 2 3 5 6 9 11 16 19 20 ...
```

I have now created an empty data.table `problem` with rows that I want to use to summarise the elements that are over the limit in `mydata`:

```
  problem <- data.table("LIMITid" = character(),
                        "LIMITtype" = character (), 
                        "LIMITvalue" = character (), 
                        "amount" = double(), 
                        "customerID" = character())
```

Finally, i want to populate my `problem` data.table with the corresponding information. I tried:

```
if(length(n) > 0){
 problem$LIMITid <- limit$id
 problem$LIMITtype <- limit$type
 problem$LIMITvalue <- limit$value
 problem$amount <- mydata$amount
 problem$customerID <- mydata$customerID
}
```

How can i populate the `data.table`? I was thinking of using a loop, but i am unsure how to loop over positions in an element - `n %in% nrownames(mydata)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols` and then subset the `.SD` (Subset of Data.table) with the index provided by 'n' and `cbind` with the 'limits' dataset

```
library(data.table)
cbind(limits, mydata[, .SD[n], .SDcols = c("amount", "customerID")])
```

Comment: isnt this binding the columns?

Comment: @Danka Except for the `cbind`, this is the data.table way

Comment: ah ok i see... i found the `.SD`part a little confusing, but i see  that `.SD[n]` takes all the rows i need... great thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work ?

```
library(data.table)
data.table(limits, amount = mydata$amount[n], customerID = mydata$customerID[n])
```

Comment: this creates new columns `amount` and `customerID`, resulting in duplicate column names... but otherwise, yes, that is exactly what i am after ... How can i avoid creating new columns and instead use the existing ones?

Comment: just foud out: `limits <- data.table(amount = mydata$amount[n], customerID = mydata$customerID[n])`

Comment: is there a different way how to solve this... my workaround results in error after all

Comment: @Danka How do you get duplicate columns? `limits` does not have `amount` and `customerID`, right? Additionally, you can change the name to anything you want. I don't understand what error you get?